# Python - Casting Error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to code a program that will print the total price after a discount. If the price `paid` is over `100`, it will knock off `20%`. At the end of the program, I receive this error:

```
if paid>=100:
    TypeError: unorderable types: str() >= int()
```

Here is my Code:

```
paid=input('How much did you pay? ')
if paid>=100:
    actualPay=100*1.25 #20% off total, 100/0.80 = 1.25
    print(actualPay)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cast the `input` to an `int`

```
paid=int(input('How much did you pay? '))
```

[`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) always returns a string. You need to explicitly cast it.

Ex:

```
paid=int(input('How much did you pay? '))
if paid>=100:
    actualPay=100*1.25
    print(actualPay)
```

A better way would have a `try` and `except` block.

```
try:
    paid=int(input('How much did you pay? '))
    if paid>=100:
        actualPay=100*1.25
        print(actualPay)    
except TypeError:
        print "Please enter a valid input."
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't know how I missed that.

Comment: Input does not always return an string. input is Equivalent to eval(raw_input(prompt)). Maybe the input cannot be is converted to\ an integer.

Comment: @RobertJacobs Maybe you are using Python2. The OP is using Py3 :). Check the link for the python3 `input` function